# Get $_SERVER['HTTP_HEAD'] through an iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

I want to know if it's possible to get the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] of a page calling the PHP script through an iframe.
For instance: index.html having  and have test.php get the HTTP_HOST of index.html
If that makes any sense :P

Google/Bing/etc has been absolutely worthless on this and I can't be the only new-ish-to-PHP person wondering :(

context: I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to display an ad on a site. If at all possible, I'd like to be able to send everything using an iframe calling a PHP script, then send different ads depending on which site the request is coming from :)

Comment: make the site include some sort of id as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to find out where the iframe content has been called from.

You could then for example make use of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to find the hostname

```
$parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$domain = $parsed['host'];
```

Comment: The referer doesn't have to be filled though